# Shifted uv coordinates

Tags: c++, blender, directx-11

I am trying to create a model loader for my game engine which takes a .obj objectfile (from blender) and converts it into a model with indices and vertices, but the uv coordinate seems shifted and very incorrect.

Here's the code for the model loader:

```
bool RawModel::LoadModel(std::string fileName)
{

    m_name = fileName;

    int pos = m_name.find_last_of("\\");
    if (pos >= 0)
    {
        m_name = m_name.substr(pos + 1, m_name.length());
    }

    //Load vertices:

    m_vertices.clear();
    m_indices.clear();

    std::ifstream objFile(fileName);
    if (!objFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open file: " << fileName << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::string currentLine;

    std::vector<Vector3> vertices;
    std::vector<Vector2> uvs;
    std::vector<Vector3> normals;

    while (objFile.good())
    {
        std::getline(objFile, currentLine);
        if (currentLine.find("v ") != std::string::npos) //Vertex
        {
            std::stringstream streamedLine(currentLine);
            float x, y, z;
            std::string temps;
            streamedLine >> temps;
            streamedLine >> x;
            streamedLine >> y;
            streamedLine >> z;
            vertices.push_back(Vector3(x, y, z));
        }
        else if (currentLine.find("vt ") != std::string::npos) //Uv
        {
            std::stringstream streamedLine(currentLine);
            float x, y;
            std::string temps;
            streamedLine >> temps;
            streamedLine >> x;
            streamedLine >> y;
            uvs.push_back(Vector2(x, 1-y)); //-y because top is 0y not 1y as in normal coordinate space
        }
        else if (currentLine.find("vn ") != std::string::npos) //Normal
        {
            std::stringstream streamedLine(currentLine);
            float x, y, z;
            std::string temps;
            streamedLine >> temps;
            streamedLine >> x;
            streamedLine >> y;
            streamedLine >> z;
            vertices.push_back(Vector3(x, y, z));
        }
        else if (currentLine.find("f ") != std::string::npos)
        {
            m_vertices.resize(vertices.size());

            std::stringstream streamedLine(currentLine);
            std::string segment;
            streamedLine >> segment;
            std::vector<std::string> indices;

            indices.reserve(3);

            //getting the triangulated face to a array
            while (streamedLine >> segment)
                indices.push_back(segment);

            for (int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i++) //Loop all indices in the face
            {
                std::stringstream streamedIndex(indices[i]);
                std::vector<int> vertex;//0 = vertexPos, 1 = uv, 2 = normal
                indices.reserve(3);

                while (std::getline(streamedIndex, segment, '/')) //x3
                {
                    vertex.push_back(stoi(segment)-1);
                }
                m_vertices[vertex[0]] = VertexType(vertices[vertex[0]], uvs[vertex[1]]);
                m_indices.emplace_back(vertex[0]);

            }

        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`VertexType` is a struct which is the structure of the vertex.  The vertex is built up and is defined like this:

```
struct VertexType
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 position;
    D3DXVECTOR2 uv;
    D3DXVECTOR3 normal;
    VertexType() : position(0, 0, 0), uv(0, 0) {};
    VertexType(D3DXVECTOR3 position, D3DXVECTOR2 uv, D3DXVECTOR3 normal) :position(position), uv(uv), normal(normal) {};
    VertexType(Vector3 position, Vector2 uv) :position(position.D3DXVECTOR()), uv(uv.D3DXVECTOR()) {};
};
```

This is how it should look when it working correctly

[image: BlenderPreview]

and this is how it looks in my game engine:

[image: Game engine]

I doubt its wrong with the model because it works in unity and blender with the same texture (the green and red is outside of the uv coordinates according to the uv layout where the transparent parts normally should be but made green and red for ease.) (red at the bottom of the texture and green at the top)

This is the texture used in both cases.
[image: The used texture in both cases]

Comment: One mistake - you are pushing both vertices and normals to the `vertices` vector, so you get twice as many vertices, half with bad locations. At the end you have `m_vertices[vertex[0]] = VertexType()` but this is a face you are reading, do you make a list of faces? Faces are normally where the uv data goes, note that you get more uvs than vertices, this is because each vertex has a position at the corner of multiple faces. For example a cube, each vertex is used by three faces with each face using a different uv location for the same vertex.

Answer (score 0):

Having loaded in OBJ files, I remember this issue.  And my fix in C# which Im sure you can apply here is following.

```
vp.SetTextureUV(result.Textures[TextureIndex].X, -result.Textures[TextureIndex].Y);
```

When you set the V component of your UV, I had to negate the value for some reason in the format, to get it to work with my texture.  I hope this also resolves your issue.  From the screenshots, I think it will.

You could flip your texture on the Y axis, that should do the trick also.